# how to delete all occurences of an item in a linked list?

Tags: java

im a beginner with linked lists and this my very first attempt to write a method call removeall(N) that will delete all occurrences of a certain element within the list. Im traversing the list and if i see an element that is equal to n im removing the link however  Im getting an error saying

```
 Exception in thread "main" 22 at LinkList.removeAll(LinkList.java:34)
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

can someone please explain what im doing wrong ?

Link.java

```
class Link
   {
   public long iData;              // data item
   public Link next;              // next link in list
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public Link(long id) // constructor
      {
      iData = id;                 // initialize data
                       // ('next' is automatically
      }                           //  set to null)
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public void displayLink()      // display ourself
      {
      System.out.print("{" + iData  + "} ");
      }
   }  // end class Link
```

Linkedlist.java

```
class LinkList
{
    private Link first;            // ref to first item on list
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    public LinkList()              // constructor
    { 
        first = null; }           // no items on list yet
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    public boolean isEmpty()       // true if list is empty
    { 
        return (first==null); }
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    public void insertFirst(long dd) // insert at start of list
    {                           // make new link
        Link newLink = new Link(dd);
        newLink.next = first;       // newLink --> old first
        first = newLink;            // first --> newLink
    }
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    //public long deleteFirst()      // delete first item
    public Link deleteFirst()      // delete first item
    {                           // (assumes list not empty)
        Link temp = first;          // save reference to link
        first = first.next;         // delete it: first-->old next
        return temp;          // return deleted link
    }

    public void removeAll(int n) {

          Link current = first;       // start at beginning of list
          while(current != null)  {
              current = current.next; 

              if(current.iData==n) {
                  current.next=current.next.next;



              }




          }

    }
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    public void displayList()
    {
        System.out.print("List (first-->last): ");
        Link current = first;       // start at beginning of list
        while(current != null)      // until end of list,
        {
             System.out.print("List (first-->last): "+ current.iData);    // print data
            current = current.next;  // move to next link
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
}  // end class LinkList
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a few issues in your removeAll implementation:

1. `if(current.iData==n)` checks the value of the current list item but  `current.next=current.next.next;` removes next item.
2. You don't handle the matches in the beginning on the list.

Try the following implementation of the removeAll method:

```java
        public void removeAll(int n) {
            // handling elements from the beginning
            while(first != null && first.iData == n){ 
                first = first.next;
            }

            // Removing matched elements from the rest of the list
            Link current = first;
            while (current != null && current.next != null ) {
                if (current.next.iData == n) {
                    current.next = current.next.next;
                } else {
                    current = current.next;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Posting code to an answer that is clearly for a homework question can be bad, but it depends on the case. Sometimes it's appropriate for an explanation. I would definitely say outright solving a homework question for a user that hasn't done any work themselves would almost uniformly be bad though. For your answer, it's good you added an explanation. That said, now I've read your code and I see a problems you've introduced. You actually can't handle an element at the end of the list.